# I am interested if I need to obtain tourist visa befora I start my journey to USA or it can be obtained at the airport with an EU passport?

Tags: visas, usa, bulgarian-citizens

I own EU passport (Bulgarian) and plan to visit USA as a tourist. I need some info on visa matter.

Comment: What did you look into so far?

Answer (score 3):

There are no visa-on-arrival procedures for the US.

All travellers<sup>*</sup> (even those in transit) fall in one of these categories:

1. Are exempt (means, you don't need a visa). These visitors fall under the VWP (Visa Waiver Program). In this case, the traveller needs to obtain travel clearance in advance, called the ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization).
2. Need a visa. For general visit/tourism; the common visa type is the visitor (B-2) visa. This must be obtained in advance of travel.

Unfortunately, Bulgaria is not one of the countries whose citizens or nationals can enter the US under the VWP. So you'll need to obtain a B-2 visa in advance of your travel.

Please contact the [US Embassy in Bulgaria](http://bulgaria.usembassy.gov/) for more information and procedures.  Note that during busy travel seasons (like summer/winter holidays or at the start of the academic season) the embassy gets quite busy; so it is advised to apply well in advance.

---

<sup>*</sup> There are some exceptions to this rule, for example [citizens of Canada and Bermuda](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/canada-bermuda.html) do not need visas or ESTA if they are travelling for tourism.

Comment: (+1) But I think there is a third category: Canadians, who need neither a visa nor an ESTA. And all of this also applies to passengers in transit.

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for your two initial claims?

Comment: @JoErNanO [Yes](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit.html) and [Yes](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html).

Comment: Canadians are mentioned in one of your links too and I see that citizens of Bermuda are also visa exempt.

Comment: It's your answer of course but you could also simply do a third bullet point ;)

Comment: Add them to your answer, then. ;)